# OpenCV: Without modifications, input video file smaller than output file

Tags: python, opencv, video, compression

I am currently using OpenCV in python to read from a video .mp4 file which is ~300kb in size, 1min and 20sec long. I have noticed that if I read each frame from the file, and write said frame to a new file using OpenCV's functionalities, my new video copy is ~50Mb... can someone explain how this is possible and how to fix it?

The codec for both files is the same: H.264

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/video.mp4')

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 50.0, (160, 210))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Quite likely different settings for the compression than what was used to generate the original. You could try changing the quality setting, but that might not be enough (or even supported). Keep in mind that OpenCV is a Computer Vision library. The Video I/O functionality there is a convenience to support developing computer vision systems.

Comment: To me it makes no sense than reading and writing the same file frame by frame generates two files of different size..

Comment: The same thing can happen with JPEG (the lower the quality, the smaller the resulting file). Even with non-lossy compression, like zlib (used in PNG), you can change the compression level, trading time to compress for size of the resulting file.